# How does Spring Kafka consider a record or batch as processed?

Tags: spring-kafka

Found this from Spring Kafka documentation:

BATCH: Commit the offset when all the records returned by the poll() have been processed.

RECORD: Commit the offset when the listener returns after processing the record.

I wanted to know how does it get considered it as "processed"? Is it the kafka listener received a message and finished without any errors? Suppose it gets stopped in between due to some reason(app stopped, some exception occurred) will it be considered processed?

Also in case of ackMode = BATCH for a non batch listener what will happen? Will it act like ackMode = RECORD? Committing one record at a time?

I wanted to confirm these behaviours are right or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Processed" in this context means the listener exited normally; if the listener throws an exception, the behavior depends on the configured error handler. By default, the error handler will re-seek the partitions and redeliver the failed record up to 10 times (with no delay between attempts), you can modify that by configuring an appropriate back off.

With `AckMode.BATCH` and a record listener, the previously processed records will be committed before calling the error handler.

See the documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#annotation-error-handling

Comment: Does CommonErrorHandler reseek to the beginning of previous poll or to current record offset? And also why does it need to reseek at all if next poll will poll from same offset as it is not committed?

Comment: That's not how Kafka works - Kafka maintains 2 pointers; the last committed offset and the current position; they are unrelated except the position is set to the last committed offset when the consumer starts. The next poll won't fetch uncommitted records; it will fetch the next batch following the last record in the previous poll. Hence a seek is required to re-fetch the failed record (until retries are exhausted) and the following records from the previous poll.

Comment: Offsets for the records before the failure are committed.

Comment: @GaryRussell With AckMode.BATCH, a record listener & the default error handler what happens if the spring application is going to shut down and the consumer's `stop()` method is called? Do spring-kafka listen on the shutdown event and commit the processed offset before shutting down the application? spring-kafka version 3.0.11.

Comment: By default, the container will process and commit all records from the last poll before stopping. If the `stopImmediate` container property is true, the container will stop after the current record, commit the offsets, and any remaining records from the poll will be redelivered on the next start.

Answer (score 1):

If the listener is set to `ackMode=BATCH`, the container will commit the offset only when all records returned by the `poll()` method have been processed successfully. For single records, `ackMode=BATCH` will behave similarly to `ackMode=RECORD`.

If the listener is stopped mid-process, the offset will not be committed, and the record or batch will be processed again in the next poll cycle.

For a non-batch listener with `ackMode=BATCH`, it will behave like `ackMode=RECORD` and commit the offset for each processed record individually.

Comment: I wanted to know how does it get considered it as "processed"? Is it executing it without any errors?